# How do I reference a serverless-framework custom property from within a javascript module?

Tags: javascript, serverless-framework

I have a [`serverless` module I've written in `javascript`](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#reference-variables-in-javascript-files), and I want to use a custom property, but I don't see any examples in the [`Serverless Variables` documentation](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/) of how to do so.

Example property:

```
custom:
  foo:
    prod: abc
    dev: def
```

In the `Reference Variables in Javascript Files` section, they show the following module:

```
// config.js
module.exports = serverless => {
  serverless.cli.consoleLog('You can access Serverless config and methods as well!');

  return {
    property1: 'some value',
    property2: 'some other value',
  };
};
```

So I assume I should be able to access my `foo` property through the `serverless` closure parameter somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Custom properties are available at:

```
serverless.service.custom['<property name>']
```

Thus, for my `foo` property, I would use

```
serverless.service.custom['foo']
```

or

```
serverless.service.custom.foo
```